# Microsoft Access 2016 SQL Unnest Array

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to take a table and in Microsoft 2016 Access and use SQL to unnest a single column into multiple rows instead.  It is comma separated.

```
SELECT BOGO_Sale.Summary, BOGO_Sale.issue_key, BOGO_Sale.promo_name, BOGO_Sale.promo_parent_sku_names, BOGO_Sale.promo_parent_skus
FROM BOGO_Sale;
```

I tried adding Unnest and keep getting errors, maybe I am missing something.

This `BOGO_Sale.promo_parent_skus` is the only column I am trying to unnest into rows.

An example of the table is:

[image: example table of data]

Here is an example of what I want my SQL query to turn the data into:

[image: example of what I want the output of my SQL query to be]

The data from my source system comes this way (long story) so I just need to convert it so I can do other analysis and work on it.

The version of Microsoft Access I am using is Office 365 ProPlus Access 2016 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unnest` does not exist in [MS Access SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference).

To accomplish this in MS Access, you'll likely need to use the VBA [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) function to convert the content of your `promo_parent_skus` field into an array, and build an output table containing the results.

Something like:

```
Function ParseBOGO()
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sku
    Dim fld As Field

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    dbs.Execute "select t.* into BOGO_Output from BOGO_Sale t where false"

    Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("bogo_sale")
    Set rs2 = dbs.OpenRecordset("bogo_output")
    If Not rs1.EOF Then
        rs1.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs1.EOF
            For Each sku In Split(rs1!promo_parent_skus, ",")
                rs2.AddNew
                For Each fld In rs1.Fields
                    rs2.Fields(fld.Name) = fld.Value
                Next fld
                rs2!promo_parent_skus = sku
                rs2.Update
            Next sku
            rs1.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs2.Close
    rs1.Close
End Function
```

The above will generate a new table called `BOGO_Output`.

Comment: Works perfectly.  I have never used VBA before.  I get it now, appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I assume if I needed to reverse the BOGO output file, I could just use a STUFF() function to convert into comma separated also?  Sometimes we want to do the reverse to input into a different system for execution after doing filtering and analysis of this list.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad it works. Almost anything can be achieved with enough code... for the reverse process you may want to consider Allen Browne's `ConcatRelated` function.